# Правильное составление php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Нужно вывести строки с одной таблицы, при условии, что поле у этих строк будет равно полю с другой таблицы, допустим `id`?

**Как правильно составить запрос с помощью `php pdo`?**

- нужно учесть то, что в первой таблице идентификатора может и не быть, и запрос вернет false.

В конце нужно получить массив такого вида:

```
0
    pole1 = 123
    pole2 = 123

1
    pole1 = 123
    pole2 = 123
2
    pole1 = 123
    pole2 = 123
3
    pole1 = 123
    pole2 = 123
```

Comment: структуру таблиц не помешало бы и примерные данные

Comment: Как то так: SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.field_id

Comment: А структура таблиц государственная тайна?